# Attempting a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
x <- 1:19
count <- 0
for (i in x) {
  if atranspose * T5_5_FBEETLES[i, 3:6]>cutoff
  count=count+1
}
print(count)
```

Hello, I am trying to do a for loop in R. In this for loop, I am multiplying a 1x4 matrix (atranspose in this case) and the third through sixth columns of a table (the table is T5_5_FBEETLES in this case) row by row (hence the i in x, so going through the first 19 rows) and I'm comparing it to a number with the variable name of cutoff. If the multiplication ends up with something greater than the cutoff number, I want count to increase by  1. I know from doing this by hand that by the end count should be 19, but for whatever reason my for loop returns 1 for my count variable and I keep getting these two errors:

unexpected symbol in:
"for (i in x) {
  if atranspose"

unexpected '}' in "}"

Can anyone explain to me why these two errors are occurring, and how I can fix up my for loop so that it can return the correct count?

Comment: You need brackets after the if ... `if (atranspose * T5_5_FBEETLES[i, 3:6]>cutoff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because your if statement crosses a line and thus needs some curly braces:

```
x <- 1:19
count <- 0
for (i in x) {
  if (atranspose * T5_5_FBEETLES[i, 3:6]>cutoff) {
  count=count+1
}
}
print(count)
```

This will then give you another error because the logical check of the if statement will return a vector, so it needs to be wrapped in an any:

```
x <- 1:19
count <- 0
for (i in x) {
  if (any(atranspose * T5_5_FBEETLES[i, 3:6]>cutoff)) {
  count=count+1
}
}
print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I am getting the outputs I was looking for now!